# Find $P$ for which dice game Never ends?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> We throw a dice with a probability of $p$ to get a Head (Thus $1-p$ to
> get a Tail). We keep playing until we get a Tail **for the first time.**
>
> Find for which values of $p$ the game ends
> after finite number of steps with a probability of 0.

**My try:**

The game ends after finite number of steps with a probability of 0 **is the same as** the game never ends with after finite number of steps with a probability of 1 ie only for every $p$ that isn't 1.

What's wrong with my solution, how can we appoach such question?

Comment: Your solution is correct, why do you think there's something wrong with it?

Comment: @user6247850 1) My professor used to solve these questions with the help of lim sup and **Borel–Cantelli second lemma**. 2) I didn't prove formally that for any p that isn't 1 the game will ebd after finite number of tries has probability bigger than 0.

Comment: I added an answer that I think addresses your comment.  In the future, it would be a good idea to include the information in that comment in your original question - it helps to provide context for your question, and lets everyone know what kind of answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think Borel-Cantelli is a bit of overkill here.  If you want to rigorously prove that the game ends after a finite number of steps for all $p < 1$, we can show the probability it lasts an infinite number of steps is $0$.  Let $A_{\infty}$ be the event that the game continues infinitely, and $A_n := \{\text{the game lasts at least }n \text{ steps}\}$.  It is clear that $\mathbb{P}(A_\infty) \le \mathbb{P}(A_n) = p^n$ for all $n$.  If $p < 1$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p^n = 0$ so sending $n$ to infinity in the inequality $\mathbb{P}(A_\infty) \le p^n$ gives $\mathbb{P}(A_\infty) = 0$.

Comment: to use Borel-Cantelli it should happen that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n) < \infty$$ which doesn't hold in your case in addition to the codition that all of them are unrelated which doesn't hold again. Probably you should define it to be "we got head in turn n".

Comment: @John I didn't use Borel-Cantelli, so there's no need to check its hypotheses.  Regardless, $\sum \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \sum p^n$ is a geometric series and therefore finite for $p < 1$.

Comment: you are right, but what about dependancy. you should show $A_n$'s are independant of each other...

Comment: @John Sure, if I wanted to use the second form of Borel-Cantelli, I would need to show the $A_n$ are independent.  However, my proof didn't use Borel-Cantelli and doesn't require independence of the $A_n$.

Comment: that's what I'm saying they are dependant... and I want to use Borel-Cantelli

Comment: @John There are multiple ways to solve this problem, and Borel-Cantelli doesn't seem to be the most natural way to do so.  Borel-Cantelli tells us about events happening infinitely often, so you'd have to make some sort of argument about the game ending in finite steps is contained in the event that you get tails infinitely often.

Comment: Thanks, so final answer is only for p=0 right?

Comment: The game ends after a finite number of steps with probability $0$ if and only if the probability of tails is $0$, i.e. $p = 1$.